# Can git maintenance prefetch task be restricted to a subset of remotes?

Tags: git, git-maintenance

I can't find a way to restrict prefecting done by scheduled git-maintenance runs to just some remotes and not all of them. I'd like to do it because I have many remotes that are only used occasionally and may be not available at all (e.g. one refers to a testing machine which is often offline) and getting errors like

```
systemd[nnn]: Failed to start git-maintenance@daily.service - Optimize Git repositories data.
```

in the journal is annoying.

Is there something I'm missing or is it really not implement and you have to prefetch all or nothing?

Comment: Seems to be impossible currently. [The docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance#Documentation/git-maintenance.txt-prefetch) says: "*updates the object directory with the latest objects **from all registered remotes**.*" — emphasize mine